# adding one selectlistitem to another selectlistitem in c#

Tags: c#, list, model-view-controller, selectlistitem

I have a two list where values get added from back end

```
List(SelectListItem) listItem = _db.tbl1(s => s.uc_name).Select(n =>
                                           new SelectListItem
                                           {
                                               Value = n.uc_id.ToString(),
                                               Text = n.uc_name
                                           }).ToList();

 List(SelectListItem) listitems1 = _db.tbl2.OrderBy(s => s.Description).Select(n =>
                                           new SelectListItem
                                           {
                                               Value = n.ID.ToString(),
                                               Text = n.Description
                                           }).ToList();
```

I want to insert `listitems1` in `listItem`

```
listItem.Insert(listItem.Count,(SelectListItem)listitems1);
```

but it shows me error as

> cannot convert from generic list to system.web.mvc.selectlistitem

Comment: Your `listitems1` is `List<SelectListItem>` type. You cannot cast it to `SelectListItem` type.

Comment: To add list into list, you need [List<T>.AddRange(IEnumerable<T>) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=net-5.0).

Comment: what is the suitable way for adding one selectlistitem to another selectlistitem

Comment: **adding one selectlistitem to another selectlistitem**. Do you mean add to **single** `SelectListItem` or `List<SelectListItem>`. If add to **single** `SelectListItem`, I don't think it works as based on your attached code, you try to add element(s) into `List<SelectListItem>`.